# Android studio and tomcat server

Tags: java, android, tomcat

I’m trying to post to a RESTful web service hosted on a tomcat server from android studio but I don’t know the correct media type to use, I can get data from the restful web service but I cannot seem to post to it. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with IDE tags just because you use that IDE: these tags should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging)

Comment: It could be a permissions problem. What media types have you already tried? Are you using Retrofit or something similar?

Comment: This answer could possibly help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321559/415-unsupported-media-type-for-xml-post-rest-api